# Firebase Phone Auth 'Invalid Token' Error After Enabling APNs in iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing an iOS app with Firebase phone authentication for login and registration. This setup was functioning correctly until I integrated Apple Push Notification Service (APNs) for direct push notifications from the backend (not via Firebase). Post this integration, and enabling APNs in Xcode, I'm encountering an 'invalid token' error specifically when attempting Firebase authentication.

This is the firebase auth code during login where I am facing error:

```
    let verificationID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authVerificationID")
        
        PhoneAuthProvider.provider()
            .verifyPhoneNumber(self.phone_no, uiDelegate: nil) { verificationID, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("-----------PHONE AUTH:",error.localizedDescription) //Getting invalid token here
                    return
                }
                UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVerificationID")
            }
```

This is the code I added for push notifications in AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { success, _ in
            guard success else {
                return
            }
            print("Success in APNS registry")
        }
        
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        
        
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
        
        
        return true;
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data -> String in
            return String(format: "%02.2hhx", data)
        }
        let token = tokenParts.joined()
        UserInfo.apnToken = token
        print("Messaging Delegate Token: \(token)")
        print("Messaging Delegate Token UserInfo: \(UserInfo.apnToken)")
        //NotificationUtils.updateDeviceToken();
    }
```

I expected Firebase authentication to continue working as before, even after APNs integration. However, the introduction of APNs seems to be conflicting with the Firebase auth token. I've not made any changes to Firebase settings in the console post-APNs setup.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like its doing swizzling in order to get the push token, then when you explicitly get it yourself, it now no longer has access to it.

I don't know this Firebase API but presumably there must be an api for you to pass it the push token after you've obtained it yourself.

See their doc about swizzling and how to turn it off etc

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Comment: Thank you for the advice. As per the documentation, we tried to disable method swizzling by adding the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled in the app’s Info.plist file and setting it to No. Unfortunately, this approach hasn't resolved our issue. Are there any additional steps or changes required to effectively disable swizzling?

Additionally, we noticed that our app's bundle ID differs between Firebase and what we have registered with Apple's APN service. Could this discrepancy be contributing to the problem we're experiencing?

Comment: "app's bundle ID differs between Firebase and what we have registered with Apple's APN service." When a push it sent, its sent to a specific bundle id, using a token which is associated with the bundle id, if there's a mismatch there's going to be problems.

Comment: We created a new Firebase app using the same app bundle ID that's registered with Apple's APN service. After creating this new Firebase app, we replaced the GoogleService-Info.plist file in our project with the new one generated.
We have also ensured that method swizzling is disabled, as per the earlier advice. Despite these adjustments, we're still encountering the 'Invalid Token' error during phone authentication.